# How to Achieve asynchronous reply using TCP send receive methods?

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, tcp, async-await

The situation I am trying to implement is as follows:

- Application A is written in C#.
- Application B is written in JavaScript. (Does not support WebSockets 
  because it's Photoshop Extend Script)

Earlier, both applications communicated using Files with support of fileWatchers. Moving to TCP sockets for communication now.

I have written a TCP server in Application A. Application B can make a connection and communicate.

The problem is that I want to communicate in an async/await fashion. For example application A wants some data from application B. A send a tcp message to B, B should respond to that and as a result A continues it's execution from that point.

```
var info = await sendTCPmessageToB();
// do something from info.

public async Task<int> sendTCPmessageToB()
{
    String message = "ABC";
    var reply = await TCPServer.sendMessage(message);
    return reply;
}
```

I have created my server using this https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/24758/tcp-async-socket-server-client-communication

I have altered the code to add in IStateObject:

```
private Action callback;
```

which keeps a callback, but this seems a hassel as I cannot pass the callback to the TCPServer class.

I am currently stuck not sure that if I will achieve the result using current method. Please let me know what other best ways to accomplish this.

Comment: If you don't know, did you try?

Comment: I am trying to pass the action to StateObject but for every request, I have to set a new action.